# Python not editing file correctly

Tags: python, gpx

Should be simple to fix, but I can't see the problem here.

```
a = 18
b = 30
c = 00
input = open('13.gpx', 'r')
output = open('14.gpx', 'w')
for line in input.readlines():
    if line == '<time>2014-01-19T18:30:00Z</time>':
        d = str(int(a))
        e = str(int(b))
        f = str(int(c))
        output.write('<time>2014-01-19T' + d + ':' + e + ':' + f + 'Z</time>')
        c = c + 18.4712
        if c >= 60:
            b = b + 1
            c = c - 60
        else:
            print('hi')
        if c >= 60:
            a = a + 1
            b = b - 60
        else:
            print('hi')
    else:
        output.write(line)
```

I've tried a lot of things, but it always just prints off the original file, and doesn't change any of the timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

Your code logic is:

For each line in the file:

1. If it's `'<time>2014-01-19T18:30:00Z</time>'`, build an exact duplicate of the line and write it to the output file; or
2. If it isn't, just write it straight to the output file.

What exactly are you expecting to change between the two files?

Comment: I put "c = c + 18.4712", so surely the time should count up by about 18 seconds between each instance of the timestamp in the file?

Comment: Exactly 18 seconds, in fact, as you use `int()`. But Martijn is correct; that never matches without `'\n'` or `strip()`.

Answer (score 1):

Lines of text from a file end with a newline, so your equality test won't work:

```
if line == '<time>2014-01-19T18:30:00Z</time>':
```

Strip whitespace from the start and end of the line:

```
if line.strip() == '<time>2014-01-19T18:30:00Z</time>':
```

There is no need to cast integers to `int` again, and if you use string formatting there is no need to cast to `str()` either:

```
output.write('<time>2014-01-19T{}:{}:{}Z</time>'.format(a, b, int(c))
```

You may want to rename those three variables to `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds`, and fix the error you have in your `if c >= 60:` lines; most likely you wanted one of those to test the minutes, the other the seconds; you are now only testing if the seconds value (`c`) overflows, twice.

You don't need to use `file.readlines()` either; you can loop *directly* over the file object; it'll yield lines:

```
for line in input:
```

I would use a different name than `input`; you are masking the built-in `input()` function now.

Comment: This works great but it stops after the first 586 lines, any idea why?

Comment: @user3212959: no idea why, unless you only *have* 586 lines. There is nothing in the code to stop looping.

Comment: also line 568 doesn't line up between the two files, so some lines are missing? Oh dear

Comment: @user3212959: Again, nothing in this loop is causing that; perhaps your `if` line is still too strict for the input?

Comment: Okay now it works for every line but the last line, but still refuses to process past 568 lines

Comment: @user3212959: I recommend you add some `print` statements and trace where your understanding is lacking.